# Error: "Timeout was reached" ? My miktex does not update/download any packages?

Tags: packages, miktex

My miktex does not downlaod or update any package. The error in the Miktex console for updating or downloading packages is "Timeout was reached"

Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: I can update without problems, so the problem is local. You can try to switch the repository, or wait some time. Or check if you have some proxy or firewall which interferes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer
How can I "switch the repository"?
How can I "check if you have some proxy or firewall which interferes"?

sorry for asking elementary questions